# svn export with revision numbers in the exported filenames

Tags: svn, export, revision

I need to export files from one folder, and want to mark (extend the file name) with the real file revision. There is not that sort of option in `svn export`. However, maybe someone has a script that does this?

Comment: Are you working on linux or windows?

Comment: Windows generally but if can find quick solution can use linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

As a start you can use something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Name | Foreach-Object {svn info $_ --show-item last-changed-revision}
```

This will print out the latest revision of every file.
If You need Recusrion just add `-Recursive` to the Get-Childitem.

In Powershell you can get help for `Get-ChildItem` with the command: `Get-Help Get-ChildItem`.